# Can I use thymeleaf syntax inside of javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

Here is the part of the code that I try to take out to .js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#buttonCancel").on("click", function () {
    window.location = "[[@{/users}]]"; 
});
});
```

and link to this file from .html right before close body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/userForm.js?v=1}"></script>
```

If I click "Cancel" I have an error 400. Yes, I can use "window.location = "/myweb/users";" and it works well. But I am curious if there any way to use th-syntax in javascript file?

Comment: Looks l8ke you have several  typos, th: is wrong as is the @{ and the }, should probably be <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/userForm.js?v=1"></script>, which is a relative path.  If you are having trouble with it, replace it with a full http url

Comment: window.location should be a url. not -"[[@{/users}]]";

Comment: Yes, I can use "window.location = "/myweb/users";" and it works well but the question is is there way to connect thymeleaf with javascript?

Comment: Hi @Tom  what are tech stack are you using and what function do you need to perform?

Comment: Java 17, html 5, Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, Mysql. I can use thymeleaf in html code but I can't use this in js. That is the question.

Comment: You can do this... but you'd need to set up controllers for your JavaScript (the same way you have controllers for your HTML pages) and then treat your JavaScript files the same way (in a templates folder etc... they are no longer static resources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative, you could create a hidden link in your HTML, and then use it in your script:

HTML:

```html
<a id="cancelAction" style="display:hidden" th:href="@{/users}"></a>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buttonCancel").on("click", function () {
        $("#cancelAction").click();
    });
});
```